# What to do when you can not save a password as a hash

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords

I have a program that uses `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext` to verify that the information a user entered in a setup screen is a valid user on the domain (the computer itself is not on the domain) and do some operations on the users of the domain. The issue is I do not want the user to need to enter his or her password every time they run the program so I want to save it, but I do not feel comfortable storing the password as plain-text in their app.config file. PrincipalContext needs a plain-text password so I can not do a salted hash as everyone recommends for password storing.

This is what I did

```
const byte[] mySalt = //It's a secret to everybody.
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
public global::System.Net.NetworkCredential ServerLogin
{
    get
    {
        var tmp = ((global::System.Net.NetworkCredential)(this["ServerLogin"]));
        if(tmp != null)
            tmp.Password = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetString(ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(tmp.Password), mySalt, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
        return tmp;
    }
    set
    {
        var tmp = value;
        tmp.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(ProtectedData.Protect(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(tmp.Password), mySalt, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
        this["ServerLogin"] = value;
    }
}
```

Was this the right thing to do or is there a better way?

EDIT --
Here is a updated version based on everyone's suggestions

```
private MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
public global::System.Net.NetworkCredential ServerLogin
{
    get
    {
        var tmp = ((global::System.Net.NetworkCredential)(this["ServerLogin"]));
        if(tmp != null)
            tmp.Password = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(tmp.Password), md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp.UserName.ToUpper())), DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
        return tmp;
    }
    set
    {
        var tmp = value;
        tmp.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(ProtectedData.Protect(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp.Password), md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp.UserName.ToUpper())), DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
        this["ServerLogin"] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Who and what are you trying to defend the password from?

Comment: I would say 'proper' way would be keeping the Kerberos ticket, but I don't know how in this context, sorry.

Comment: @Slaks - I am defending the password from bored coworkers who have sat down at someone else's computer. I just want to protect from the casual observer, not a determined hacker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing `new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()`, you should write `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`.

Also, I recommend using UTF8 instead.

Other than that, your code looks pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the other way to use the encoder. Why do you recommend UTF8 over ASCII?

Comment: Joel's idea of using per-username salts is an excellent suggestion and I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

For the salt, I'd do a transformation on the username (hash it) rather than share the same salt for everyone.

For something like this, I'd also look for a way to keep the existing session alive longer rather than saving the password to create new sessions.

Comment: The session is alive the entire instance the program is run, I just need to create the session with the server when the program starts, or did you mean keep the session alive between runs?

Comment: You could use a service or other background program to hold the session and keep it alive longer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the JoelCoehoorn approach.

Use a value unique for the user machine as the password salt.

So it will be different in each deplyment ; ).

UPDATE: See this thread for ideas: [How-To-Get-Unique-Machine-Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872385/how-to-get-unique-machine-signature)

Comment: What is the same user logs on to different machines?  It's got to be per-user.

Comment: Hi Joel thanks for asking : )

If the user change from pc to pc: he will need to enter its domain credentials again necessarily, before caching ; )

Comment: It can be either user or machine. that is what the last parameter DataProtectionScope is for.

Comment: Yes, but since the machine isn't in a domain, even per-user will also be per-machine.