# Safe way to handle password in C# Win Forms App

Tags: c#, password-protection

I have a little application in C#
it uses Web Browser Control to log me in, onto a web site

Then I press a button, to generate a word file using Docx

I use my login id and password (hard-coded) to login

I want to know how I can distribute my application among other
colleagues so that they can use my exe file (or generated setup) to enter
their id n password once, and then use application without any worry

I can write n read id n password to config file, but I dont know how safe it is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3101911/1336590 - regarding the first point: a .Net application can very easily be disassembled so everyone interested in it would know which kind of encryption you use.

Comment: You can use application's config file. And set encrypted password for each user.

Comment: possible duplicate of a old question of mine: [What to do when you can not save a password as a hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273496/what-to-do-when-you-can-not-save-a-password-as-a-hash). It pretty much is asking the exact same question and has the solution to protect the password on a per-user basis so that two users on the same machine could not read each-others passwords.

Comment: What if I use a database (such as MS Access File)
to store an encrypted password?

And if the dot net application is easily dis-assembled, then what is the best recommended option I have ?

Comment: Please also tell me is it OK to save password in simple variable?
in this case, the application shall require the pwd every time