# ID or a serial number that all Windows computer have and that can't be changed

Tags: c#, windows

I'm creating a program that authenticates from a before it runs. I also want to deny access. Is there an id or a serial that all Windows computers have that can't be changed, that I could put on a black list? And how would I access that in C#?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99880/generating-a-unique-machine-id. It gives a couple of alternative approaches.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that people often swap hardware in and out of their systems. You wouldn't want your software to stop working simply because someone bought a new NIC or upgraded their video card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAC address can actually be changed quite easily.

This article: has info on exactly what you want: [How To Get Hardware Information](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx).

Basically, just mix a few of the hardware component IDs, and you should have a pretty solid key for your system.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of CUPID, hard disk volume ID and MAC address would be a good choice. They won't be changed unless with hardware changes. (However, HD vol. ID would be changed if you format the disk)

Comment: In a previous job we fell back on the hard disk ID for licensing. We knew it wasn't ideal, but it was something.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of restriction on access is generally accomplished by a hardware dongle or by a licensing server.  Without these, specifically identifying a particular PC as the 'allowed machine' is a tricky proposition and anything you choose is likely to be spoofable.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, off the top of my head MAC address would be a good choice.  It *could* be changed by getting a new NIC card, but it's not super easy to change.

Comment: MAC addresses can generally be changed via a pretty UI for most cards. Generally in the driver settings.