# How To Get An Unique ID?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can i get an unique id from one of installed hardwares? Something like h.d.d serial or motherboard, ....?
Thanks

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852134/how-to-generate-an-unique-computer-id-on-delphi

Comment: However, after long time searching, I used cpuid to get my uniaue id. If someone needs to know more just tell me to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this URL : http://www.diskserialnumber.com/

http://www.diskserialnumber.com/get-disk-serial

Better one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx

Comment: Be careful with the one from code project as I am not 100% sure it works on all operating systems, esp. vista

Comment: True story, noticed it 3 years later :p!

Answer (score 0):

We use http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp and are very happy with it.

Comment: I have this unit already, but i'm not sure it works fine on every sytem. You sure about this? Does work on any H.D.D (Sata, IDE,..) or any OS? And what about laptops?

Comment: By the way, when i click for disk serial in windows xp (as it said) it returns null, and for motherboard just returns model, no serial!!

Comment: Sorry, Armin, but we haven't extensively tested it on different platforms. It's one of many checks we use to determine if a user has moved his software to another computer after licensing.

Comment: Why would someone downvote my answer here?

Comment: good question! answer was useful!