# in Delphi7, How can I retrieve hard disk unique serial number?

Tags: delphi, hardware, delphi-7

Hi
I want to retrieve HDD unique (hardware) serial number.
I use some functions but in Windows Seven or Vista they don't work correctly because of admin right.
Is it possible retrieve it without run as Administrator?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to generate an unique computer id on Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852134), [How To Get An Unique ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700195)

Comment: The usual reason people want this is copy protection.  Be aware that some RAID controllers will respond with the serial number of whatever drive is available to answer and thus you'll get different answers different times.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Following the links in the question comments [Sertac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243614/sertac-akyuz) posted, I came across this [interesting C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331106/how-to-get-serial-number-from-hard-disks), where [Fredou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40868/fredou) answered with a nice link to a [codeproject example showing how to do this in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/DriveInfoEx.aspx?fid=371167&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2787288), which in turn was based on a [link to Borland C++ code](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/) and [article](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html).

The cool thing is that [this C++ code](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/) works as a non-administrator user too!

Now you need someone to help you translate this C++ code to Delphi.

*Edit*: **Found a Delphi unit that does this for you.**

I wrote some sample use for it:

```
program DiskDriveSerialConsoleProject;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  hddinfo in 'hddinfo.pas';

const
  // Max number of drives assuming primary/secondary, master/slave topology
  MAX_IDE_DRIVES = 16;

procedure ReadPhysicalDriveInNTWithZeroRights ();
var
  DriveNumber: Byte;
  HDDInfo: THDDInfo;
begin
  HDDInfo := THDDInfo.Create();
  try
    for DriveNumber := 0 to MAX_IDE_DRIVES - 1 do
    try
      HDDInfo.DriveNumber := DriveNumber;
      if HDDInfo.IsInfoAvailable then
      begin
        Writeln('VendorId: ', HDDInfo.VendorId);
        Writeln('ProductId: ', HDDInfo.ProductId);
        Writeln('ProductRevision: ', HDDInfo.ProductRevision);
        Writeln('SerialNumber: ', HDDInfo.SerialNumber);
        Writeln('SerialNumberInt: ', HDDInfo.SerialNumberInt);
        Writeln('SerialNumberText: ', HDDInfo.SerialNumberText);
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(Format('DriveNumber %d, %s: %s', [DriveNumber, E.ClassName, E.Message]));
    end;
  finally
    HDDInfo.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  ReadPhysicalDriveInNTWithZeroRights;
  Write('Press <Enter>');
  Readln;
end.
```

Unit from http://www.delphipraxis.net/564756-post28.html

```
// http://www.delphipraxis.net/564756-post28.html

unit hddinfo;

interface

uses Windows, SysUtils, Classes;

const
  IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY = $2D1400;

type
  THDDInfo = class (TObject)
  private
    FDriveNumber: Byte;
    FFileHandle: Cardinal;
    FInfoAvailable: Boolean;
    FProductRevision: string;
    FProductId: string;
    FSerialNumber: string;
    FVendorId: string;
    procedure ReadInfo;
    procedure SetDriveNumber(const Value: Byte);
  public
    constructor Create;
    property DriveNumber: Byte read FDriveNumber write SetDriveNumber;
    property VendorId: string read FVendorId;
    property ProductId: string read FProductId;
    property ProductRevision: string read FProductRevision;
    property SerialNumber: string read FSerialNumber;
    function SerialNumberInt: Cardinal;
    function SerialNumberText: string;
    function IsInfoAvailable: Boolean;
  end;

implementation

type
  STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY = packed record
    PropertyId: DWORD;
    QueryType: DWORD;
    AdditionalParameters: array[0..3] of Byte;
  end;

  STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR = packed record
    Version: ULONG;
    Size: ULONG;
    DeviceType: Byte;
    DeviceTypeModifier: Byte;
    RemovableMedia: Boolean;
    CommandQueueing: Boolean;
    VendorIdOffset: ULONG;
    ProductIdOffset: ULONG;
    ProductRevisionOffset: ULONG;
    SerialNumberOffset: ULONG;
    STORAGE_BUS_TYPE: DWORD;
    RawPropertiesLength: ULONG;
    RawDeviceProperties: array[0..511] of Byte;
  end;

function ByteToChar(const B: Byte): Char;
begin
  Result := Chr(B + $30)
end;

function SerialNumberToCardinal (SerNum: String): Cardinal;
begin
  HexToBin(PChar(SerNum), PChar(@Result), SizeOf(Cardinal));
end;

function SerialNumberToString(SerNum: String): String;
var
  I, StrLen: Integer;
  Pair: string;
  B: Byte;
  Ch: Char absolute B;

begin
  Result := '';
  StrLen := Length(SerNum);

  if Odd(StrLen) then Exit;

  I := 1;

  while I < StrLen do
  begin
    Pair := Copy (SerNum, I, 2);
    HexToBin(PChar(Pair), PChar(@B), 1);
    Result := Result + Chr(B);
    Inc(I, 2);
  end;

  I := 1;

  while I < Length(Result) do
  begin
    Ch := Result[I];
    Result[I] := Result[I + 1];
    Result[I + 1] := Ch;
    Inc(I, 2);
  end;
end;

constructor THddInfo.Create;
begin
  inherited;

  SetDriveNumber(0);
end;

function THDDInfo.IsInfoAvailable: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FInfoAvailable
end;

procedure THDDInfo.ReadInfo;
type
  PCharArray = ^TCharArray;
  TCharArray = array[0..32767] of Char;

var
  Returned: Cardinal;
  Status: LongBool;
  PropQuery: STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY;
  DeviceDescriptor: STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR;
  PCh: PChar;

begin
  FInfoAvailable := False;
  FProductRevision := '';
  FProductId := '';
  FSerialNumber := '';
  FVendorId := '';

  try
    FFileHandle := CreateFile(
                     PChar('\\.\PhysicalDrive' + ByteToChar(FDriveNumber)),
                     0,
                     FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                     nil,
                     OPEN_EXISTING,
                     0,
                     0
                   );

    if FFileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    ZeroMemory(@PropQuery, SizeOf(PropQuery));
    ZeroMemory(@DeviceDescriptor, SizeOf(DeviceDescriptor));

    DeviceDescriptor.Size := SizeOf(DeviceDescriptor);

    Status := DeviceIoControl(
                FFileHandle,
                IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                @PropQuery,
                SizeOf(PropQuery),
                @DeviceDescriptor,
                DeviceDescriptor.Size,
                Returned,
                nil
              );

    if not Status then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    if DeviceDescriptor.VendorIdOffset <> 0 then
    begin
      PCh := @PCharArray(@DeviceDescriptor)^[DeviceDescriptor.VendorIdOffset];
      FVendorId := PCh;
    end;

    if DeviceDescriptor.ProductIdOffset <> 0 then
    begin
      PCh := @PCharArray(@DeviceDescriptor)^[DeviceDescriptor.ProductIdOffset];
      FProductId := PCh;
    end;

    if DeviceDescriptor.ProductRevisionOffset <> 0 then
    begin
      PCh := @PCharArray(@DeviceDescriptor)^[DeviceDescriptor.ProductRevisionOffset];
      FProductRevision := PCh;
    end;

    if DeviceDescriptor.SerialNumberOffset <> 0 then
    begin
      PCh := @PCharArray(@DeviceDescriptor)^[DeviceDescriptor.SerialNumberOffset];
      FSerialNumber := PCh;
    end;

    FInfoAvailable := True;
  finally
    if FFileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      CloseHandle(FFileHandle);
  end;
end;

function THDDInfo.SerialNumberInt: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if ((IsInfoAvailable = True) and (FSerialNumber <> '')) then Result := SerialNumberToCardinal(FSerialNumber)
end;

function THDDInfo.SerialNumberText: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if ((IsInfoAvailable = True) and (FSerialNumber <> '')) then Result := SerialNumberToString(FSerialNumber)
end;

procedure THDDInfo.SetDriveNumber(const Value: Byte);
begin
  FDriveNumber := Value;
  ReadInfo;
end;

end.
```

*Edit*: **RAID configurations require special provisions.**

For instance, I got a RAID system with multiple RAID 5 array; only the first one displays, and it does not show the drive serial numbers, but the serial number of the RAID array:

```
VendorId: AMCC
ProductId: 9550SXU-16ML
ProductRevision: 3.08
SerialNumber: 006508296D6A2A00DE82
SerialNumberInt: 688416000
```

--jeroen

Comment: Thanks for your post, Yes, I saw this code before, but I can't found any way or library for translate it in Delphi 7

Comment: @Amin maybe you can ask another question here for people to help you translate that code into Delphi?

Comment: the key elements of the code in that C++ sample are 
 h := CreateFile( Format("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%d", drive), 0,...) and then DeviceIoControl (h, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, query, ...). The rest is error checking and result checking.

Comment: @Warran: translating everything is a tedious job, especially since not all structures are in the `Windows` unit, and I don't have the Windows DDK/SDK .H files at hand. Found a unit in a German forum though (glad I speak and read German very well).

Comment: /me thanks the downvoters for not leaving a comment; now please turn back your downvote into upvote since I did edit it to add a complete working solution that does not require Admin rights.

Comment: @GJ: RAID systems require RAID-specific solutions, as a RAID disk can have multiple drive serial numbers.

Comment: I know this is not what the OP asked, but be noted the code doesn't work with SSD (which obviously is not HDD) :)

Comment: @EdwinYip that likely depends on the vendor/model of SSD. Here it worked fine with these SSDs on both Windows 10 and Windows 8.1: SanDisk SDSSDA240G, Crucial_CT960M500SSD1, SAMSUNG HM100UI, OWC Mercury Electra 3G MAX SSD, Samsung SSD 860 EVO 250GB.

Windows 10 however does find too many extra "cruft" at the end of the valid drives. One day, I might look into that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get information related to windows hardware.

Exist two wmi classes wich exposes a property called `SerialNumber` which store `the Number allocated by the manufacturer to identify the physical media.` these classes are  [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://www.google.com/search?q=Win32_DiskDrive&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&client=firefox-a&rlz=1R1GGLL_en___CL418) and [`Win32_PhysicalMedia`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).to access the `SerialNumber`  property of these classes you must know the `DeviceId` of the Disk which is something like this `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0`. Another way is use a association class which link the Physical drive with the logical drive (C,D,E)

so you must find this link previous to obtain the serial number. the sequence to find this association is like this.

[`Win32_DiskPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -> [`Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -> [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Note 1** : The `SerialNumber` property for the `Win32_DiskDrive` class does not exist in Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000, and Windows NT 4.0, so how you are talking about use Windows Vista or Windows 7, will work ok for you.

**Note 2** : The code does not require a administrator account to run.

check this code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

function GetDiskSerial(const Drive:AnsiChar):string;
var
  FSWbemLocator  : OLEVariant;
  objWMIService  : OLEVariant;
  colDiskDrives  : OLEVariant;
  colLogicalDisks: OLEVariant;
  colPartitions  : OLEVariant;
  objDiskDrive   : OLEVariant;
  objPartition   : OLEVariant;
  objLogicalDisk : OLEVariant;
  oEnumDiskDrive : IEnumvariant;
  oEnumPartition : IEnumvariant;
  oEnumLogical   : IEnumvariant;
  iValue         : LongWord;
  DeviceID       : string;
begin;
  Result:='';
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  objWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', ''); //Connect to the WMI
  colDiskDrives := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive','WQL',0);
  oEnumDiskDrive:= IUnknown(colDiskDrives._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnumDiskDrive.Next(1, objDiskDrive, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
   DeviceID        := StringReplace(objDiskDrive.DeviceID,'\','\\',[rfReplaceAll]); //Escape the `\` chars in the DeviceID value because the '\' is a reserved character in WMI.
   colPartitions   := objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition',[DeviceID]));//link the Win32_DiskDrive class with the Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition class
   oEnumPartition  := IUnknown(colPartitions._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    while oEnumPartition.Next(1, objPartition, iValue) = 0 do
     begin
        colLogicalDisks := objWMIService.ExecQuery('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="'+objPartition.DeviceID+'"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition'); //link the Win32_DiskPartition class with theWin32_LogicalDiskToPartition class.
        oEnumLogical  := IUnknown(colLogicalDisks._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
          while oEnumLogical.Next(1, objLogicalDisk, iValue) = 0 do
          begin
            if objLogicalDisk.DeviceID=(Drive+':')  then //compare the device id
            begin
                Result:=objDiskDrive.SerialNumber;
                Exit;
            end;
           objLogicalDisk:=Unassigned;
          end;
        objPartition:=Unassigned;
     end;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Writeln(GetDiskSerial('C'));
      Readln;
    finally
    CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
        Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: i've tried your code but return EOleSysError Bad variable type and pointing to this line    colPartitions   := objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition',[DeviceID]));//link the Win32_DiskDrive class with the Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition class

Comment: Which OS and Delphi version are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem with EOleSysError at this line of code. I am using Windows 7. If I compile it with Delphi 2007, it works; if I compile it with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, it does not work. Maybe it is a Unicode problem?    I couldn't find the problem, so I used this code, which worked for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292395/how-to-get-manufacturer-serial-number-of-an-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 1):

Here is another [DiskId32](http://code.google.com/p/dvsrc/downloads/detail?name=DiskId32PortForDelphi.rar&can=2&q=) translation from C++ to Delphi by Victor Derevyanko

project:
http://code.google.com/p/dvsrc/

Because the first method (WithZeroRights) doesn't work for me, I wrote another for ReadIdeDriveAsScsiDriveInNT method:

```
unit HDScsiInfo;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

const
  IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
  FILE_DEVICE_SCSI = $0000001b;
  IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT_IDENTIFY = ((FILE_DEVICE_SCSI shl 16) + $0501);
  IDE_ATA_IDENTIFY = $EC;  //  Returns ID sector for ATA.
  IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT = $0004D008;  //  see NTDDSCSI.H for definition

type
  TDiskData = array [0..256-1] of DWORD;
  TDriveInfo = record
    ControllerType: Integer; //0 - primary, 1 - secondary, 2 - Tertiary, 3 - Quaternary
    DriveMS: Integer; //0 - master, 1 - slave
    DriveModelNumber: String;
    DriveSerialNumber: String;
    DriveControllerRevisionNumber: String;
    ControllerBufferSizeOnDrive: Int64;
    DriveType: String; //fixed or removable or unknown
    DriveSizeBytes: Int64;
  end;

  THDScsiInfo = class (TObject)
  private
    FDriveNumber: Byte;
    FFileHandle: Cardinal;
    FInfoAvailable: Boolean;
    FProductRevision: string;
    FSerialNumber: string;
    FControllerType: Integer;
    FDriveMS: Integer;
    FDriveModelNumber: string;
    FControllerBufferSizeOnDrive: Int64;
    FDriveType: string;
    FDriveSizeBytes: Int64;
    procedure ReadInfo;
    procedure SetDriveNumber(const Value: Byte);
    procedure PrintIdeInfo(DiskData: TDiskData);
  public
    constructor Create;
    property DriveNumber: Byte read FDriveNumber write SetDriveNumber;
    property ProductRevision: string read FProductRevision;
    property SerialNumber: string read FSerialNumber;
    property ControllerType: Integer read FControllerType;
    property DriveMS: Integer read FDriveMS;
    property DriveModelNumber: string read FDriveModelNumber;
    property ControllerBufferSizeOnDrive: Int64 read FControllerBufferSizeOnDrive;
    property DriveType: string read FDriveType;
    property DriveSizeBytes: Int64 read FDriveSizeBytes;
    function IsInfoAvailable: Boolean;
  end;

implementation

type

  SRB_IO_CONTROL = record
   HeaderLength: Cardinal;
   Signature: array [0..8-1] of Byte;
   Timeout: Cardinal;
   ControlCode: Cardinal;
   ReturnCode: Cardinal;
   Length: Cardinal;
  end;
  PSRB_IO_CONTROL = ^SRB_IO_CONTROL;

  DRIVERSTATUS = record
   bDriverError: Byte;//  Error code from driver, or 0 if no error.
   bIDEStatus: Byte;//  Contents of IDE Error register.
                        //  Only valid when bDriverError is SMART_IDE_ERROR.
   bReserved: array [0..1] of Byte;//  Reserved for future expansion.
   dwReserved: array [0..1] of Longword;//  Reserved for future expansion.
  end;

  SENDCMDOUTPARAMS = record
   cBufferSize: Longword;//  Size of bBuffer in bytes
   DriverStatus: DRIVERSTATUS;//  Driver status structure.
   bBuffer: array [0..0] of Byte;//  Buffer of arbitrary length in which to store the data read from the                                                       // drive.
  end;
  IDEREGS = record
   bFeaturesReg: Byte;// Used for specifying SMART "commands".
   bSectorCountReg: Byte;// IDE sector count register
   bSectorNumberReg: Byte;// IDE sector number register
   bCylLowReg: Byte;// IDE low order cylinder value
   bCylHighReg: Byte;// IDE high order cylinder value
   bDriveHeadReg: Byte;// IDE drive/head register
   bCommandReg: Byte;// Actual IDE command.
   bReserved: Byte;// reserved for future use.  Must be zero.
  end;
  SENDCMDINPARAMS = record
   cBufferSize: Longword;//  Buffer size in bytes
   irDriveRegs: IDEREGS;   //  Structure with drive register values.
   bDriveNumber: Byte;//  Physical drive number to send
                            //  command to (0,1,2,3).
   bReserved: array[0..2] of Byte;//  Reserved for future expansion.
   dwReserved: array [0..3] of Longword;//  For future use.
   bBuffer: array [0..0] of Byte;//  Input buffer.     //!TODO: this is array of single element
  end;
  PSENDCMDINPARAMS = ^SENDCMDINPARAMS;

  PSENDCMDOUTPARAMS = ^SENDCMDOUTPARAMS;
  IDSECTOR = record
   wGenConfig: Word;
   wNumCyls: Word;
   wReserved: Word;
   wNumHeads: Word;
   wBytesPerTrack: Word;
   wBytesPerSector: Word;
   wSectorsPerTrack: Word;
   wVendorUnique: array [0..3-1] of Word;
   sSerialNumber: array [0..20-1] of AnsiChar;
   wBufferType: Word;
   wBufferSize: Word;
   wECCSize: Word;
   sFirmwareRev: array [0..8-1] of AnsiChar;
   sModelNumber: array [0..40-1] of AnsiChar;
   wMoreVendorUnique: Word;
   wDoubleWordIO: Word;
   wCapabilities: Word;
   wReserved1: Word;
   wPIOTiming: Word;
   wDMATiming: Word;
   wBS: Word;
   wNumCurrentCyls: Word;
   wNumCurrentHeads: Word;
   wNumCurrentSectorsPerTrack: Word;
   ulCurrentSectorCapacity: Cardinal;
   wMultSectorStuff: Word;
   ulTotalAddressableSectors: Cardinal;
   wSingleWordDMA: Word;
   wMultiWordDMA: Word;
   bReserved: array [0..128-1] of Byte;
  end;
  PIDSECTOR = ^IDSECTOR;

  TArrayDriveInfo = array of TDriveInfo;

type
  DeviceQuery = record
   HeaderLength: Cardinal;
   Signature: array [0..8-1] of Byte;
   Timeout: Cardinal;
   ControlCode: Cardinal;
   ReturnCode: Cardinal;
   Length: Cardinal;
   cBufferSize: Longword;//  Buffer size in bytes
   irDriveRegs: IDEREGS;   //  Structure with drive register values.
   bDriveNumber: Byte;//  Physical drive number to send
   bReserved: array[0..2] of Byte;//  Reserved for future expansion.
   dwReserved: array [0..3] of Longword;//  For future use.
   bBuffer: array [0..0] of Byte;//  Input buffer.     //!TODO: this is array of single element
  end;

function ConvertToString (diskdata: TDiskData;
               firstIndex: Integer;
               lastIndex: Integer;
               buf: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar;
var
   index: Integer;
   position: Integer;
begin
   position := 0;
      //  each integer has two characters stored in it backwards
   for index := firstIndex to lastIndex do begin
         //  get high byte for 1st character
      buf[position] := AnsiChar(Chr(diskdata [index] div 256));
      inc(position);
         //  get low byte for 2nd character
      buf [position] := AnsiChar(Chr(diskdata [index] mod 256));
      inc(position);
   end;
      //  end the string
   buf[position] := Chr(0);

      //  cut off the trailing blanks
   index := position - 1;
   while (index >0) do begin
//      if not IsSpace(AnsiChar(buf[index]))
      if (AnsiChar(buf[index]) <> ' ')
        then break;
      buf [index] := Chr(0);
      dec(index);
   end;

   Result := buf;
end;

constructor THDScsiInfo.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  SetDriveNumber(0);
end;

function THDScsiInfo.IsInfoAvailable: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FInfoAvailable
end;

procedure THDScsiInfo.PrintIdeInfo (DiskData: TDiskData);
var
  nSectors: Int64;
  serialNumber: array [0..1024-1] of AnsiChar;
  modelNumber: array [0..1024-1] of AnsiChar;
  revisionNumber: array [0..1024-1] of AnsiChar;
begin
      //  copy the hard drive serial number to the buffer
   ConvertToString (DiskData, 10, 19, @serialNumber);
   ConvertToString (DiskData, 27, 46, @modelNumber);
   ConvertToString (DiskData, 23, 26, @revisionNumber);
   FControllerType := FDriveNumber div 2;
   FDriveMS := FDriveNumber mod 2;
   FDriveModelNumber := modelNumber;
   FSerialNumber := serialNumber;
   FProductRevision := revisionNumber;
   FControllerBufferSizeOnDrive := DiskData [21] * 512;
   if ((DiskData [0] and $0080) <> 0)
      then FDriveType := 'Removable'
      else if ((DiskData [0] and $0040) <> 0)
          then FDriveType := 'Fixed'
          else FDriveType := 'Unknown';
//  calculate size based on 28 bit or 48 bit addressing
//  48 bit addressing is reflected by bit 10 of word 83
  if ((DiskData[83] and $400) <> 0) then begin
      nSectors := DiskData[103] * Int64(65536) * Int64(65536) * Int64(65536) +
                    DiskData[102] * Int64(65536) * Int64(65536) +
                    DiskData[101] * Int64(65536) +
                    DiskData[100];
  end else begin
        nSectors := DiskData [61] * 65536 + DiskData [60];
  end;
//  there are 512 bytes in a sector
  FDriveSizeBytes := nSectors * 512;
end;

procedure THDScsiInfo.ReadInfo;
type
  DataArry = array [0..256-1] of WORD;
  PDataArray = ^DataArry;
const
  SENDIDLENGTH = sizeof (SENDCMDOUTPARAMS) + IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE;
var
  I: Integer;
  buffer: array [0..sizeof (SRB_IO_CONTROL) + SENDIDLENGTH - 1] of AnsiChar;
  dQuery: DeviceQuery;
  dummy: DWORD;
  pOut: PSENDCMDOUTPARAMS;
  pId: PIDSECTOR;
  DiskData: TDiskData;
  pIdSectorPtr: PWord;
begin
  FInfoAvailable := False;
  FFileHandle := CreateFile (PChar(Format('\\.\Scsi%d:', [FDriveNumber])),
                             GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                             FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil,
                             OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if (FFileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then begin
        ZeroMemory(@dQuery, SizeOf(dQuery));
        dQuery.HeaderLength := sizeof (SRB_IO_CONTROL);
        dQuery.Timeout := 10000;
        dQuery.Length := SENDIDLENGTH;
        dQuery.ControlCode := IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT_IDENTIFY;
        StrLCopy(@dQuery.Signature, 'SCSIDISK', 8);
        dQuery.irDriveRegs.bCommandReg := IDE_ATA_IDENTIFY;
        dQuery.bDriveNumber := FDriveNumber;
        if (DeviceIoControl (FFileHandle, IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT,
                             @dQuery,
                             SizeOf(dQuery),
                             @buffer,
                             sizeof (SRB_IO_CONTROL) + SENDIDLENGTH,
                             dummy, nil))
        then begin
           pOut := PSENDCMDOUTPARAMS(buffer + sizeof (SRB_IO_CONTROL)); //!TOCHECK
           pId := PIDSECTOR(@pOut^.bBuffer[0]);
           if (pId^.sModelNumber[0] <> Chr(0) ) then begin
              pIdSectorPtr := PWord(pId);
              for I := 0 to 256-1 do
                 DiskData[I] := PDataArray(pIdSectorPtr)[I];
              PrintIdeInfo (DiskData);
              FInfoAvailable := True;
           end;

     end;
     CloseHandle(FFileHandle);
  end;
end;

procedure THDScsiInfo.SetDriveNumber(const Value: Byte);
begin
  FDriveNumber := Value;
  ReadInfo;
end;

end.
```

Sample usage:

```
procedure ReadIdeDriveAsScsiDriveInNT;
var
  DriveNumber: Byte;
  HDDInfo: THDScsiInfo;
begin
  HDDInfo := THDScsiInfo.Create();
  try
    for DriveNumber := 0 to MAX_IDE_DRIVES - 1 do
    try
      HDDInfo.DriveNumber := DriveNumber;
      if HDDInfo.IsInfoAvailable then begin
        Writeln('Available Drive: ', HDDInfo.DriveNumber);
        Writeln('ControllerType: ', HDDInfo.ControllerType);
        Writeln('DriveMS: ', HDDInfo.DriveMS);
        Writeln('DriveModelNumber: ', HDDInfo.DriveModelNumber);
        Writeln('ControllerBufferSizeOnDrive: ', HDDInfo.ControllerBufferSizeOnDrive);
        Writeln('DriveType: ', HDDInfo.DriveType);
        Writeln('DriveSizeBytes: ', HDDInfo.DriveSizeBytes);
        Writeln('ProductRevision: ', HDDInfo.ProductRevision);
        Writeln('SerialNumber: ', HDDInfo.SerialNumber);
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(Format('DriveNumber %d, %s: %s', [DriveNumber, E.ClassName, E.Message]));
    end;
  finally
    HDDInfo.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  ReadIdeDriveAsScsiDriveInNT;
  Write('Press <Enter>');
end.
```

This works great with my WD disk.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code, it is fixed one and working fine with me on windows 7 64

https://code.google.com/p/dvsrc/downloads/detail?name=20120116DiskId32Port_fixed.7z&can=2&q=

and this his all work

https://code.google.com/p/dvsrc/downloads/list

Comment: Please, try to summarize the contents of the pages you linked, instead of just link them.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this purely for completeness sake, and to possibly satisfy those interested or die hard hardware fanatics.

I do not have a Pascal compiler at my disposal to test these routines on current Windows systems, but I do know this code worked back in the DOS era. Maybe it still works from a command prompt window.

Pascal code:

```
uses
  Dos, Crt;

type
  SerNoType = record
    case Integer of
      0: (SerNo1, SerNo2: Word);
      1: (SerNo: Longint);
  end;

  DiskSerNoInfoType = record
    Infolevel: Word;
    VolSerNo: SerNoType;
    VolLabel: array[1..11] of Char;
    FileSys: array[1..8] of Char;
  end;

function HexDigit(N: Byte): Char;
begin
  if N < 10 then
    HexDigit := Chr(Ord('0') + N)
  else
    HexDigit := Chr(Ord('A') + (N - 10));
end;

function GetVolSerialNo(DriveNo: Byte): String;
var
  ReturnArray: DiskSerNoInfoType;
  Regs: Registers;
begin
  with Regs do
  begin
    AX := $440d;
    BL := DriveNo;
    CH := $08;
    CL := $66;
    DS := Seg(ReturnArray);
    DX := Ofs(ReturnArray);
    Intr($21, Regs);
    if (Flags and FCarry) <> 0 then
      GetVolSerialNo := ''
    else
      with ReturnArray.VolSerNo do
        GetVolSerialNo :=
          HexDigit(Hi(SerNo2) div 16) + HexDigit(Hi(SerNo2) mod 16) +
          HexDigit(Lo(SerNo2) div 16) + HexDigit(Lo(SerNo2) mod 16) +
          HexDigit(Hi(SerNo1) div 16) + HexDigit(Hi(SerNo1) mod 16) +
          HexDigit(Lo(SerNo1) div 16) + HexDigit(Lo(SerNo1) mod 16);
  end;
end;

procedure PutVolSerialNo(DriveNo: Byte; SerialNo: Longint);
var
  ReturnArray: DiskSerNoInfoType;
  Regs: Registers;
begin
  with Regs do
  begin
    AX := $440d;
    BL := DriveNo;
    CH := $08;
    CL := $66;
    DS := Seg(ReturnArray);
    DX := Ofs(ReturnArray);
    Intr($21, Regs);
    if (Flags and FCarry) = 0 then
    begin
      ReturnArray.VolSerNo.SerNo := SerialNo;
      AH := $69;
      BL := DriveNo;
      AL := $01;
      DS := Seg(ReturnArray);
      DX := Ofs(ReturnArray);
      Intr($21, Regs);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Please feel free to update this answer in order to get it working (if possible at all) in Delphi.