# get hardware id using wpf

Tags: wpf

tried using solutions posted here [How to fast get Hardware-ID in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333149/how-to-fast-get-hardware-id-in-c) and here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I but it seems wpf doesn't have ManagementObjectCollection. I've already add

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
```

in my code, though. is there any way using wpf to get the cpu id and else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTF?

WPF should be able to use WMI.

Did you try manually adding a reference to System.Management (WMI)?

Comment: uh thanks.. I don't know that we had to manually add the reference to System.Management before