# Installation file for C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, software-distribution

I have created a application to learn C# , web service and created a setup file using visual studion 2010.

While installing it ask for person name and license key.The license key can be validated in both offilene mode and online mode.

**In online Mode :**
this Licese key is validated using web services.
Note: My data base for license key is in external server .

**Offline Mode**
the application validates the license key by itself. using some encryption decryption technique.

The key which we use to validate the installation is generated by another application.
To generate the key, the person has to give me his name which he will provide during the installation. Based on that i will provide him the license key.

Now my problem , i want to stop that person using the same setup file to install in another computer using the same key i provided him for the first time installation.

Can any one help me solve this.Also i am very new to c# , so i request you to explain in the easiest way.

Thanks

_

One more thing to add for Offleine mode :

For the Offline mode : i sell my application to an organisation , and they want to install in 5 diffrent machines and i dont want to give them 5 different License .

can any one help me to think inright direction ???

Thanks..

Comment: Search this site for "software licensing". This topic has been discussed many times here in depth.

Comment: thanks for the keyword to search. Security to license key in online mode is easy. For the offline mode use the unique id of the hardware to create a license key.

But i have one more issue in offline mode which i could not find in this site. I have edited in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to include some other means of identification than just the name as base of your license key - for example some hardware specific identifier(s) which don't change often.

See here: [How to fast get Hardware Id in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333149/how-to-fast-get-hardware-id-in-c)

Comment: Yes I totally agree with your solution.This solution will only work if i sell my application to one person. If i sell my application to organisation and they want to install it 5 times and i dont want to give them 5 different license key.

Comment: You'll have to sell them some sort of a license server software which enables them to activate their software n times. Of course you'd need to protect the license server as well so they can't just install it somewhere else and relicense the software with it. Another idea which may be easier would be to just sell them a hardware dongle for each installation.