# UnityEngine .NET 3.5 Get HardwareID without System.Management

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was looking for a way to get the user's HWID using this: [How to fast get Hardware-ID in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333149/how-to-fast-get-hardware-id-in-c)

but failed. System.Management is not fully ported on UnityEngine 4 and I need to find an alternative, to atleast gain access to a CPUID or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, CPUID is not computer specific, all processors of the same model type all share the same CPUID. Unique id's in the CPUID stopped happening around the late 1990's with the pentium processor generation.

Comment: Then the BIOS ID would be more applicable.

Comment: Most BIOS's don't publish it and the ones that do have it disabled by default. Are you planning on making your game run on windows only? If so there are some simple options you can do.

Comment: Nah. It is running on linux too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html) it is built in to unity. One thing to check however is it can return the value of `SystemInfo.unsupportedIdentifier` if it is running on a platform that does not provide a way to get a unique id.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start () {
        if (SystemInfo.unsupportedIdentifier != SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier)
        {
            // use SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier
        }   
    }
}
```

Be sure you are running Unity 4.6.2 or newer as [there was a bug for it on linux not returning consistent values](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/systeminfo-dot-deviceuniqueidentifier-changes-for-each-connected-network) but it was fixed in 4.6.2.

Comment: Well R.I.P. I'm on 4.5.5f1, and can't change since I'm haxing myself into game dlls. Thanks though that should be fine. Can people change that though?

Comment: `SystemInfo.unsupportedIdentifier` was not defined before `2017.4`, is there an equivalent string to test for in older Unity?

Comment: @JesseChisholm it is available, it is just if you change versions on the docs website it does not keep you on the page. Here is the 2008.1 version https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I didn't mean the in the documentation, I meant in code.  When using Unity OLDER THAN 2017.4 (such as 5.6) is there some known value similar to `System.unsupportedIdentifier` that could be checked? or just hope that the `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` is empty if it is not supported?

Comment: @JesseChisholm `System.unsupportedIdentifier` [is available in 5.6](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-unsupportedIdentifier.html). You don't need to know what the value is. Just do `if (SystemInfo.unsupportedIdentifier != SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier) { ... }`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for mentioning that. It never occurred to me that a document page what said it was only available as far back as 2017.4 ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-unsupportedIdentifier.html ) was also available in an unlinked legacy version ( https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-unsupportedIdentifier.html )

Comment: I currently use WINAPI to build a better HWID system. I suggest you try to do that. Mine consists out of CPUID, BIOSID, BASEID, GPUID, and some other extra stuffs.

Comment: @DreTaX yes, but that only works on windows if your game is going to be cross platform you can't do it.