# HardwareID without System.Management in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, hwid

I already asked this question here: [UnityEngine .NET 3.5 Get HardwareID without System.Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202709/unityengine-net-3-5-get-hardwareid-without-system-management)

But seems like It can be changed. Is there anything else I could use? Some sort of C++ code? Anything that would be useful to make hash of?

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: Windows. i managed to get CPUID and Disk using C++ libs but it may not be enough.