# How would you personally identify workstation by MAC address if there are several Ethernet adapters?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mac-address, native-code

I have to identify workstation by unique identifier that must be stable. I decided to use MAC address but what shall I do if there are several ethernet adapters (some of them may belong to VMWare installed)? Wich one shall I choose?

I use [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and deal with [IP_ADAPTER_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures.

May be you shall choose another approach to unique (and stable) workstation ids than using MAC addresses?

It's a pitty - workstation for me is "read-only". I can't automatically generate some unique identifier to create, store and reuse on workstation.

Comment: Why did you choose to use a non-unique identifier to uniquely identify workstations? Wouldn't it have made more sense to use an identifier that each workstation is guaranteed to have precisely one of?

Comment: Is there any other way to identify workstations? I can't use and store programmatically generated unique identifiers - workstation for me is "read-only"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a unique machine id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99880/generating-a-unique-machine-id)

Comment: There are plenty. If they're on the same network, you're guaranteed that their IP addresses will be unique (the same should be true for the machine names, on any sane network). or check the question I linked to above, for ways to get unique identifiers directly from Windows or the underlying hardware.

Comment: Of course, if you do use MAC addresses, you can simply pick the numerically smallest one, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're bent on MAC addresses, how about either select just the first MAC address in the list, or XOR them together?

However, I'm sure Windows has some GUID for the computer itself somewhere, which might be more along the way Microsoft intended things to work?

Comment: I'm afraid to take the fist address because it may belong to VMWare stuff and can be artificial (not unique). I also afraid to XOR MacAddresses because I'm not sure the result should be unique. May be I shall contain them one by one - but does VMWare keeps its MAC addresses stable?

Comment: Maybe you can check the adapter name and filter out VMWare virtual adapters?

Comment: XOR might not be unique, true. How about SHA-1 hashing everything? That'd be unique enough. However, I'd still recommend looking for a Windows-installation GUID somwhere, and use that.

Comment: @Andrew: concern about XOR is fair enough, it's more likely to generate a collision than a strong hash. But do bear in mind that MAC addresses are not guaranteed to be unique either. Sometimes they're configurable, and manufacturers of NICs have occasionally messed up and shipped dupes.