# Get the Value of a Registry Key in C#

Tags: registry, key-value

I am trying to get the value of a registry key. I have the following code:

```
const string keyName = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ansoft\HFSS\2014.0\Desktop";
string value = (string)Registry.GetValue(keyName, "LibraryDirectory", null);
```

I keep getting null for value. Here is a screenshot of the registry key in regedit:

[image: Regedit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer here: [Registry.GetValue always return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491958/registry-getvalue-always-return-null)

Comment: I looked at that post earlier, and it did not work for me. I kept getting null on the OpenSubKey.

Comment: Did you try to set your build architecture to Any CPU?

Comment: Yes it is defaulted to Any CPU and I am in Debug mode.

Comment: It was a problem with the architecture. Had to change it to x64. Thanks for the help