# Registry Key Mapping

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building an application in which I need to be able to gather information from the user's local Registry, and then utilize that to perform various tasks. I know where the certain registry key is located, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly extract the data. Here is the one I am trying to extract:

My ideal event would happen as follows: the utility searches for the registry value, determines it and stores it (in a var or something), then a button is displayed to the user to proceed to the next screen (I'm using WinForms). I have already set the button as "invisible" beforehand. See the attached code.

[image]

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\DovetailGames\FSX\10.0"))
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        Object o = key.GetValue("Install_Path");

        if (o != null)
        {
            sc3op2.Visible = true; //Button is "sc3op2"
        }
    }
}
```

I guess my main problem is the formatting of the code to extract these values. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: not sure, but I think your problem is you need to remove `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` from the "path" you use, since with `Regisrty.LocalMachine` you are already in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: @GianPaolo That didn't work by itself but that I can see why it's wrong, I'll take it out but no luck yet.

Comment: The path in the code includes `10.0` category at the very end which is different from the screenshot where it is missing. Is it intentional?

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko Not at all. Fixed, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492014/920557). Apparently, it has something to do with the virtualization of the application settings for 32 and 64-bit platforms. See the updated section `If it returns null, set your build architecture to Any CPU`. On my 64-bit platform, I am getting null when built using x86 or Any CPU build configuration. But it is returning the value when built using x64.

```
const string keyName = @"Software\Wow6432Node\DovetailGames\FSX";
var o = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName, false);
var value = o?.GetValue("Install_Path", "-");
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
You need to use @ before the string.

take a look [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzi6u.png)

```
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Apple Inc.\Apple Application Support"))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object o = key.GetValue("Installdir");

                if (o != null)
                {
                  // do something
                }
            }
        }
```