# Unique ID for devices in Windows

Tags: windows, device

Is there a device property for each device that is unique to that specific device instance only (such as a GUID or ID string)?

I would prefer a GUID but an ID string would be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a unique machine id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99880/generating-a-unique-machine-id)

Comment: `DEVPKEY_Device_LocationPaths`, presumably.

Comment: By "device" do you mean "computer"?

Comment: No like a USB device. DEVPKEY_Device_LocationsPaths obviously would be unique but is there something shorter in length that would be easier to compare? Like DEVPKEY_Device_Driver? (The Device instance driver key). I don't know if that is unique though.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: not a duplicate, the OP wants to ID individual devices, not the machine as a whole.

Comment: I shouldn't think DEVPKEY_Device_Driver would be unique; there are often multiple devices running under the same device driver.  I think the path is the only property guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Yeah thats true. I just need something shorter than the path that is easy to compare.

Answer (score 0):

The [Device Instance ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids) is a unique identifier for any device in a single system (read: as long as they are attached to it).

However, since you were talking about USB devices, you can have a Device Instance ID which is unique for that device, even if that's plugged on another system / machine, if the USB device provides a serial number AND the manufacturer guarantees that the serial number is unique for that USB (VID, PID) pair.
See my detailed answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885175/).