# Reading registry value on windows with QSettings

Tags: windows, qt, registry, qsettings

I'm trying to read **MachineGuid** key from windows registry using **QSettings**.

The address to that key is

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography".

I'm using the **QSettings** with **QSettings::Native** flag as follows.

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography",QSettings::NativeFormat);
```

I can see all the subfolders and their keys and the value of **MachineGuid** from **regedit.exe** but the **value** function of **QSettings** does not seem to be working correctly.

the results are as follows:

```
settings.value("MachineGuid").toString();
```

returns empty QString.

```
settings.childGroups();
```

returns all the subfolders of Cryptography folder correctly.

```
settings.childKeys();
```

returns an empty QStringList

```
settings.allKeys();
```

returns all the keys inside Cryptography folder including the keys inside of all subfolders except for `MachineGuid` which is placed inside Cryptography.

I'm using Qt 5.7.1 built statically using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

I have tried codes that use **Window.h** header and I have successfully extracted the value but the problem with this approach is that I have to add lots of DLLs to my released software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For accessing 64 Bit Windows OS with 32 Bit compiled code, the right format would be "`Registry64Format`" and if accessing 32 Bit OS from 64 compiler the the right format is "`Registry32Format`"
So, in my case, after setting format to 64 bit, the key could be fetched.

to read key "MachineGuid" on 64 bit OS with 32 bit Compiled code;

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography",
QSettings::Registry64Format);
auto key = settings.childKeys().at(0);
```

Comment: Hey Mohammad thanks for the answer but i think you have to see for yourself that if you click on cryptography on MachineGuid appears the right side of your regedit it is not a group. The problem is that Cryptography contains a key and bunch of groups as children

Comment: @mostafaTmj No I don't have that key in my system

Comment: oh... I thought every windows machine has that key as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99880/generating-a-unique-machine-id

Comment: and here is another example of the MachineGuid with a picture at the end https://www.nextofwindows.com/the-best-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-windows-machine

Comment: Oh sorry, I could see it now! but I know the problem anyway!

Comment: @mostafaTmj, sorry for that but I updated my answer: the idea is QSettings needs to know you are editing 64 bit registry (or 32 bit if compiler is 64) in that case `NativeFormat` wont help, you need to use `Registry64Format`

Comment: Great and sorry again @mostafaTmj I didn't notice it because I probably used `regedt32` instead if `regedit` !